# Searchbar not displaying correct image Swift Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, filter, tableview, searchbar

I have created a fully functioning tableview that populates its data from a text array (String) and an image array (PFFile). I have also implemented a search bar that displays the filtered results based on the created text array.

```
var fruitArray = [String]()
var imageFile = [PFFile]()
```

the problem is that fruitArray[indexPath.row] is filtered according to the input in the search bar but, the search bar cannot filter anything from imageFile and imageFile[indexPath.row] is displayed as if nothing has been searched.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print(fruitArray[indexPath.row])

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        cell.labelFruitName?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]

    } else {
        cell.labelFruitName?.text = fruitArray[indexPath.row]

    }
    let placeHolder = UIImage(named: "plchlder.png")
        cell.fruitImages?.image = placeHolder
        imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                cell.fruitImages?.image = downloadedImage



            }

        }

    return cell
}
```

as a result, the images won't change inside the cell. in other words, before searching anything, if the first cell shows a text and picture of an apple, after the search, the first cell will always display an apple but the text and number of cells change. 
Any solutions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create an array of type `[fruit]` , where fruit is just a struct with an image and a string. Then you can filter out the bad apples.

Here is the code for the struct:

```
struct Fruit {
    let name: String
    let image: PFFile
}
```

Then in your searchResultsUpdating function just filter out your search term using a simple filter:

```
results = fruitArray.filter{$0.name.containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!)}
```